# When I am trying to import VisualRecognitionV3 in Xcode it gives me the error module compiled with swift 3.0 cannot be imported in swift 3.0.2?

Tags: swift, xcode, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

When I am trying to import VisualRecognitionV3 in Xcode it gives me the error:

> module compiled with swift 3.0 cannot be imported in swift 3.0.2

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please visit the help section to understand what type of questions you can ask and how to write a good question,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.  Questions not meeting the criteria usually get closed and removed.

Comment: Can you provide more information on your environment by running `xcodebuild -version` and `swift --version` from the command-line? Also, can you try again after rerunning carthage and importing the frameworks into your project, to ensure that the frameworks are built with these same versions?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the [version issue](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-swift/issues/1) seen here.  Basically, refraining from using the precompiled binaries when calling carthage will fix the issue so use the following carthage command - "carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries"